# Building an AWS Elastic Beanstalk platform from an AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

I have configured an EC2 server with a specific set of packages and created a custom AMI from the instance which is setup just how I like it. I would like to use Elastic Beanstalk to generate a new instance with the same setup. Is that possible? When I am asked to select a platform in EBS my custom AMIs are not available to me. I cannot "apply" an AMI to an existing EC2 created by EBS. 
I would like to know how Elastic Beanstalk makes use of custom AMIs. I cannot find a clear answer in the docs.

Comment: I have read the docs and created an AMI. "It probably isn't going to work"... What probably isn't going to work? Making it work is the part I'm asking about ;)

Comment: Yes it was created from a base EBS AMI

Answer (score 1):

By default Elastic Beanstalk only provide Amazon Linux in case Linux OS. You can use your custom AMI with ElasticBeanstalk. In the AMI selection stage paste the AMI-ID of your custom AMI and you are good to go.